# from table database to gridview and opposite

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void BindPrimaryGrid()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "select * from Land";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    gridview2.DataSource = dt;
    gridview2.DataBind();
}
```

which gets the values from Land and transfer them to the gridview2. I would like to do the opposite. From the gridview2.DataSource i want to insert the values in Land. How can i do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=474895

//If DataSource of GridView1 is a DataTable

DataTable dt = (DataTable)GridView1.DataSource;

//If DataSource of GridView1 is a DataView

DataView dv = (DataView)GridView1.DataSource;

Comment: thank you for your help. I would like to ask you something. In this link which you post me what is the value gvr?

Comment: Its a GridViewRow. I hope that's what you were asking

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark this as answer, if it solved your problem. Its the big tick under the score. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supposing Table "Land" has 3 columns: col1,col2,col3. Please refer to the following code. In case of any problem, do report.

```
con.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    String insertData = "INSERT INTO Land (Col1,Col2,Col3) VALUES (@Col1,@Col2,@Col3)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col3", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
con.Close();
```